# How Disable a specific module on Zend Framework 2 dynamically

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

How to disable a specific module in ZF2 using a database
I have a list of modules in the configuration file
thinking that at some point in my application, read a table with the names of modules and disables them that are flaged as disabled in the database

in my case I am using Doctrine2 as my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazy-loading module manager from Vincent Blanchon may be a solution to your problem. It allows to conditionnally enable or disable modules.

https://github.com/blanchonvincent/zf2-lazy-loading-module

Answer (score 0):

the `application.config.php` is one of the first elements loaded by the zf2 bootstrapping and are passed to the `ServiceManager` wich loop all Modules (and load) listed in the `application.config.php`. At this point doctrine is not loaded (so you can't check if a module is "actived" in you'r database ) with a script running with zend framework.

when you check the `public/index.php` you are able to see the line where the bootstrapping begin

> // Run the application!
>
> Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();

this is your point where you logic should be implement (establish a database connection, create a application config) and pass it to the `init()` method.

but this is not a good idea, because you need to specify a db connection, set db passwords etc. and "go your own way without zf2".

when you disable modules dynamicly i think you make something "wrong", because either you need a module or you don't - either a module is enabled in development environment and disabled in your live environment. simple as it

Comment: the problem is that I need develop a modules manager , with the option to install or not one or more modules in my dashboard, like the extensions manager of wordpress, is there another way to do this?

Comment: just the way i pointed out or like in magento where the module manager is a full indipendent site besides the normal application. where one application controlls the extensions off the other application. like ``composer``.

Comment: Interesting, could you explain me better?

Answer (score 0):

I have better way to do this

just load only application module in application config file

in **application.config.php**

```
'modules' => array( 

    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule', 
    'Application',

),
```

then write a method in application/module.php called

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager) {

        $moduleManager->loadModule('xyz'); // xyz module will be fetched from db here or depend on you logic.


    }
```

Now your module is loaded by your db.